# Bootstrap v3.1 - mixins.less is throwing error on line 648, I have not changed anything

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I have recently downloaded the latest version of Bootstrap(3.1.0). I have only been using my own custom less file to style this project so far. I opened up the navbar.less and commented out a small portion (just bg-color and border-color) that was conflicting. When I re-compiled (using Less compiler by incident57.com) I received a syntax error from mixins.less on line 648.

```
ParseError:Syntax Error on line 648
647  padding-right: (@grid-gutter-width / 2);
648  &:extend(.clearfix all);
```

I haven't touched the mixins.less file. I did see another question regarding this particular error and line of code however it was in relation to using JS to compile Less which I am not doing. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: don't comment out parts from libraries. why not simply override the rules you want in your custom stylesheets?

Comment: I agree, that's probably a better way to go. That being said, I've just now removed the bootstrap less files, and re-added them to the project from the source package. It's still throwing this particular error and I haven't touched any of them. I'm going to go the overriding route, still curious why this is happening in the event I wanted to import additional less files into the main bootstrap file.

Comment: are you importing the original (unchanged) files? if so, try to import the main file alone, rather than specific files. there can be dependencies in such files, so it's best to only include the main file (in sass that would be `bootstrap.scss` rather than e.g. `_mixins.scss`).

Comment: I've got the same issue. Were you able to find a solution?

Comment: I did not come across a solution as of yet. I've bypassed the issue by taking Eliran's advise and just overwriting styles that conflict in my own custom less file. That appears to working well. I'd still be interested in finding a solution though in the event that I wanted to introduce a new less file to the main bootstrap less.